# Make probabilities with geospatial data

Tags: python, geopandas, software-recommendations, pysal

I work on a particular area, my data are geospatial types and are stored in a geodataframe which contains:

- a *structure* column (house, building, town hall, store etc).
- a *neighbors_structure* column which has been deduced from the graph representing the *n closest structures* for each structure.
- a *geometry* column, of type POINTS in my case. All structures are located and are an ID that I do not put here for the sake of brevity. Also, the GPS coordinates given here are hypothetical.

For example, with n=2 we can have:

```
   structure            neighbors_structure                    geometry
0  house                      house - house     POINT (42.70275 9.94481)
1  building        store - building - house     POINT (42.70030 9.94783)
2  house           building - store - house     POINT (42.69700 9.97133)
3  house                   store - building     POINT (44.18208 10.27975)
4  house              house - house - house     POINT (43.17099 10.52153)
...
```

Using this geodataframe, I would like to answer the following types of questions:

- If we have a structure of type _ there is a _% chance that its closest neighbor is a _

For example : *if we have a structure of type ***house*** there is ***30***% chance that its nearest neighbor is ***a building***.*

- If we have a structure of type _ there is a _% chance that in a window of _km2 we find at least one _
- If we have a structure of type _ there is a _% chance that within a radius of at least _km we find another structure

Does a powerful tool to do this exist?

I'm not sure that [Pysal](https://pysal.org/) for example allows to do exactly that with simple POINTS.

Comment: It doesn't take a powerful tool to do this; even a lightweight tool could accomplish this with a modicum of persistence. All you need to do is identify the neighbors for each parcel and compile/reduce the result. What have you tried?

Comment: @Vince Indeed I did the neighbor count for each parcel, but what do you mean by compile/reduce? I don't see how to get the probabilities out. Can you give me an example?

Comment: If you have a table of {origin,neighbor} all you need to do is sum them for {origin,neighbor,ncount}, and again for {origin,ocount} then correlation percentages are {origin,neighbor, ncount*100/ocount}.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand. I tried to use the `str.get_dummies()` and `corrwith()` methods of pandas on both columns but I don't see exactly how obtain exactly correlation for one structure versus **just** another. Somewhat similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51241575/calculate-correlation-between-columns-of-strings/51241909) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48873233/is-there-a-way-to-get-correlation-with-string-data-and-a-numerical-value-in-pand).

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the chapter on spatial weights in a new PySAL [book](https://geographicdata.science/book/notebooks/04_spatial_weights.html).

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".